# Flash Builder 4 - using relative paths with the -output (-o) compiler argument

Tags: flash, compiler-construction, parameters, arguments, flash-builder

I'm trying to use a relative path in the -output compiler argument, here's what I've tried (with and without quotes):

```
-o="./deploy/file.swf"

-o="/./deploy/file.swf"

-o="./file.swf"

-o="/./file.swf"

-o="file.swf"

-o="file.swf"
```

None of these attempts yields a new file, it's as if they are ignored. The deploy directory is in the root of my project directory. If I use an absolute path, it works great, but the project is less portable. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a good answer, but ANT allows you to create absolute paths from relative ones.